# Application Close on DialogResult

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, messagebox, dialogresult

I have a C# GUI application. When the user clicks on the red 'X' (for closing the app) I want to show a message and ask if he really wants to close it.

I found a solution:

```
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "SomeTitle", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
        {
          //don't do anything
        }
```

When the user clicks 'yes', the application should terminate completely. (Is Application.Exit() correct for this purpose?)

When the user clicks 'no', the DialogResult/MessageBox should close, but the application should stay opened. However, it closes!!

How can I avoid this?

BTW: I use Visual Studio 2010 and Winforms.

Comment: Don't do this; it's really annoying.

Comment: I always hope for a "Yes, dammit!" button on such a dialog so it will never ask me such a silly thing again, but haven't seen one yet.  Set the this.DialogResult property back to None to prevent it closing.

Comment: sorry but this isn't very helpful. it is a requirement to implement this, so thats why i am asking;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **FormClosing** event from the Form, and the [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) to cancel the process.

example:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialog = dialog = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program?", "SomeTitle", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I should expect 3 almost equal responses :(.

Comment: the e is the formcloseingeventargs.   e.cancel means cancel the formclosing, therefor it will reamin open.

Comment: I am use the this code to my  first form. It's working correctly. again I used this code to my 2nd form in that application. but It's working not correctly. two times comes confirmation box exit the application. why that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the form's `FormClosing` event of your program window. You can then set `e.Cancel` to `true` if the user clicks *no*:

```
this.FormClosing += (s, e) => {
  DialogResult dialog = dialog = MessageBox.Show("Really close?", "SomeTitle",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
  if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
};
```

I guess you are using `FormClosed`. Are you? Then it's too late.

Comment: Good point.  FormClosed is called after FormClosing in the event list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(delegate(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit this application?", MessageBoxButtons:=MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Mudu's answer.

Basically unless you specify additional parameters to `MessageBox.Show()` you cannot get any result other than `DialogResult.Ok` from a default `MessageBox`.

The code you posted (minus your little typo of `dialog = dialog =`) works exactly as expected to me.

Also: `Application.Exit()` **IS** the correct way of closing an application :)