# How can I pervent a regular user from closing my GUI, in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I want to make a GUI where if the user tries to close it they have to answer a popup (Msgbox). I know it can be closed forcefully by cmd or taskmngr, I just want the user to answer a popup or else the window wont close.

I already have the GUI ready, I've tried to remove the "closing" event on the window but that gives me an error.

Comment: Have you looked through the available events for a Form? There is one for when the form is closing.

Comment: The form has a `Closing` event. This has a `Cancel` property. If you subscribe and set it to true, the application won't close.

Comment: This question was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504887/application-close-on-dialogresult

Comment: @Oliver you mind sending a block of code so I know what you mean by `subscribe and set it to true` ?